How does NASA calculate trajectory at planetary atmosphere entry
NASA lands missions such as the Perseverance Mars Rover land at specific spots. I understand they can de-orbit to those spots to explore them, but the aerodynamic drag from the atmospheric re-entry would slow the craft and change its trajectory. So how do they calculate where the rover would land after entry?



So how do they calculate where the rover would land after entry?

By simulations, multiple simulations of various levels of fidelity. A very simple simulation can be built in a spreadsheet. While simple, spreadsheets do offer some nice search capabilities. This very simple simulation would use a very simple model of the atmosphere, a very simple model of the interaction (e.g. drag) between the spacecraft and the atmosphere, and a very simple model of Mars gravity. While very simple, this will give a fairly good idea of where to hit the atmosphere so as to arrive at the desired landing site.
This simplicity can and is changed to increasing complexity via a range of simulations. A three degree of freedom simulation (position only) might add better models of the atmosphere, the parachutes, and final descent. A six degree of freedom simulation (position and orientation) adds even more complexity and higher fidelity models, but is slower. A decent six DOF sim will certainly add randomness so that the landing ellipse can be estimated via Monte Carlo techniques (see the update below).
The next step up is a flight software in the loop simulation. This kind of simulation uses the flight software (or a close replica thereof) to control the simulated vehicle. At this point, even more randomness can be added, and also simulated failures of various kinds.
One final step is a flight hardware in the loop simulation. This kind of simulation uses a flight computer (or a close replica thereof) running the as‐coded flight software. Unfortunately, this final step results in a rather slow simulation because it has to be run at realtime, as opposed to several times faster than realtime. However, this final step is a very essential step.
Update: A brief description of landing ellipses and Monte Carlo techniques
It is highly desired to know not only where a vehicle will land but also the uncertainty in that estimate. In other words, where is the vehicle likely to land?
The initial state will not perfectly known, so the initial state in the simulation should be varied randomly. Thruster performance in a real vehicle varies from one thruster, and even varies within one thruster. These variations should also be varied randomly in the simulation. There are many other things that should be varied randomly in a simulation. These include sensor performance, atmosphere, atmosphere-vehicle interactions, and parachute performance. This is not anywhere close to a complete list.
A very simple metric for the concept of where the vehicle might land is the circle of equal probability (CEP; other names for this concept such as circular error probable also yield the same acronym). It's a single number describing the radius of a circle inside of which half of the landings will occur; this means half of the landings will occur outside of the CEP. People who don't know much mathematics or physics like this single number; people who do know those topics tend to not like this concept, for (at least) two reasons:

It would be nicer to have a better estimate of where the vehicle will land. A fifty-fifty estimation? We can do better than that.
The uncertainty along-track tend to be much higher than across track uncertainties. An ellipse is a much better model than is a circle.

This leads to the concept of the landing ellipse. One way to estimate the landing ellipse is to make several (hundreds or even several thousand simulation runs), with each run using the same basic models but each using different pseudo random number sequences. With this, an estimate of the covariance matrix can be formed. An ellipse naturally describes a two dimensional covariance matrix. The one-sigma ellipse can be directly calculated from the covariance matrix. However, this one-sigma ellipse describes where 39% of the landing might occur. A more confident ellipse is the three-sigma ellipse, which also can be calculated directly from the covariance matrix. This three sigma ellipse captures 98.9% of the landings.
Making hundreds (or even thousands) of simulation runs is what I call the basic Monte Carlo technique. The reason for needing so many simulation runs is that the accuracy of the calculated ellipse grows with ever more simulation runs, but the growth is slow as it is proportional to square root of the number of runs.
There are other ways of estimating the covariance matrix that require fewer simulation runs, sometimes far fewer. These include linear covariance analysis, Markov Chain Monte Carlo, bootstrap, and jackknife. I'm not going to go into those here as that would require a far larger update. Feel free to ask questions about these techniques.

Source for the above: Mostly myself. I spent at least 30 of my 45 year career working on simulations of various kinds, from launch to rendezvous to landing. Some of those sims were hideously complex and took a large team working for years while others were very simple.

because of the basic nature of the question, it might be worth mentioning that the Monte Carlos and the landing footprint/landing ellipse are about incorporating uncertainty into the simulations

@ErinAnne -- Updated.

For the software-in-the-loop simulations, do you deliberately test it with larger-than-expected errors to be sure the software can compensate? Or is it better to make the uncertainties as realistic as possible to get the most realistic picture of the expected behavior?

@CharlesStaats Not for things like the $3\sigma$ landing ellipse, or for nominal uncertainties during rendezvous. These assume nominal behavior. However, vehicles are supposed to be fault tolerant to some extent, so detailed simulations do have the ability to inject failures. These injected failures are not used for calculating the  landing ellipse. Another caveat: Simulation developers often rely on device manufacturers to provide the uncertainties in device behavior. The specs provided by manufacturers are typically conservative.
